# Use logstash to analize log line

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Hi I want to implement els stack for better log review, so I added logstash to ealsticsearch and kibana that already exists, logs are in form of files that was generated by .net apps that uses serilog (I know I can use serilog sink to add it directly to elasticsearch).

So I have a logstash configuration like this:

```
input 
{
    file 
    {
        mode => "tail"
        path => "/usr/share/logstash/ingest_data/*"
    }
}

filter {
}

output 
{
    elasticsearch 
    {
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        hosts=> "${ELASTIC_HOSTS}"
        user=> "${ELASTIC_USER}"
        password=> "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
        cacert=> "certs/ca/ca.crt"
    }
}
```

But I have a simple log line:

> 2023-08-17 10:10:47.253 +02:00 [Warning] [Application] Logged message

Now I see in Data View he sees timestamp source and some other default tags, but is there a possibility to define filter in such way he add information lvl like [Warning] and source as [Application]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html). You can find the already defined pattern [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/ecs-v1/grok-patterns).

```
2023-08-17 10:10:47.253 +02:00 [Warning] [Application] Logged message
```

can be parsed with

```
%{DATESTAMP:time} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:timezone} [%{WORD:level}] [%{WORD:source}] %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}
```

where the syntax is `%{PATTERN_NAME:fieldName}`.